# odoo16.com/event : Safari cant open page FetchEvent.respondWith received error: NotSupportedError: operation is not supported (WebKitServiceWorker:0)

Tags: safari, service-worker, odoo-16

I have migrated to Odoo16.
With browsers like Firefox and Chrome, all website pages are ok.

But using Safari, when i go to this specific page https://www.samadeva.com/event, i get this error:

### Safari can not open the page « https://www.samadeva.com/event Error : . FetchEvent.respondWith received an error: NotSupportedError: The operation is not supported.. (WebKitServiceWorker:0)

[image]
[image]

When i open a private window or empty cache, i get the page successfully rendered.
So far, i thought i have solved the problem...

But after a while, some of the website's visitors report that the same issue occurs again...

What i could investigate about this issue with a working older version of Safari (15.6):
[image]

It seems that this Safari WebKitServiceWorker related issue used to occur with Angular too: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/50378

... the issue is well known from Safari: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safari-release-notes/safari-17_2-release-notes#Service-Workers ...
but so far everybody needs a workaround for visitors using **16.3<Safari versions<17.3**...

Any idea how to implement this [kind of workaround (found by @gudvincent for Angular)](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/50378) in my odoo16 page's serviceWorker: https://www.samadeva.com/event/service-worker.js ?

```js
 if (navigator.userAgent.includes("Version/17.0") || navigator.userAgent.includes("Version/17.1")) {
  navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistrations().then(function (registrations) {
    for (let registration of registrations) {
      registration.unregister();
    }
  });
}
```

```js
 ServiceWorkerModule.register('ngsw-worker.js', {
   enabled:
     !navigator.userAgent.toUpperCase().includes("LIKE MAC")
       ? true
       : ((navigator.userAgent.includes("Version/17.0") || navigator.userAgent.includes("Version/17.1")) ?
         false : true)
 })
```

I have tried to inject this js workaround inside the head-tags of my websites using in odoo16: Editor > Modify > Theme > head ...:

```js
 if (navigator.userAgent.includes("Version/17.0") || navigator.userAgent.includes("Version/17.1")) {
  navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistrations().then(function (registrations) {
    for (let registration of registrations) {
      registration.unregister();
    }
  });
}
```

which work on the first call, but when clicking on another page, the error occurs again. it seems that the serviceWorker get automatically reloaded. Maybe an eventListerner would be usefull here ([Service worker activate and push event don't get triggered even though the registration is successful and it's activated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75409032/service-worker-activate-and-push-event-dont-get-triggered-even-though-the-regis)) ?

Answer (score 0):

The only workaround that i have found is to uninstall the official Odoo SA module `website_event_track` because it contains the file `service-worker.js`, that triggers the error in **16.3<Safari versions<17.3**

...
I hope that Odoo S.A will manage to fix it quickly... Their answer to my request ticket:
*<<Thank you for contacting Odoo support. There is actually already a ticket in our Bug Fix pipeline dealing with this exact issue. Please note that bug fixes may take several weeks to deploy, but I will keep you updated regarding when the fix has been done. This ticket may close automatically after 7 days without activity, but rest assured that you will be updated once more information is available. Please let me know if you have any further questions regarding this.>>*